# rails 4 : change state issue with Bootstrap Switch

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-switch

I have 3 bootstrap switches to handle  read/update/create permissions.
They area written as :

```
<%= f.check_box :allow_read, :data => { :size=>'medium', 
   'on-color'=>'success', 'on-text'=> "#{t('yes').upcase}", 
    'off-text'=> "#{t('no').upcase}" } %>


<%= f.check_box :allow_update, :data => { :size=>'medium', 
   'on-color'=>'success', 'on-text'=> "#{t('yes').upcase}", 
    'off-text'=> "#{t('no').upcase}" } %>

<%= f.check_box :allow_create, :data => { :size=>'medium', 
   'on-color'=>'success', 'on-text'=> "#{t('yes').upcase}", 
   'off-text'=> "#{t('no').upcase}" } %>
```

and displayed as :

[image: Bootstrap Switch buttons]

I am trying to use the switchChange.bootstrapSwitch method to change other é switches when one switch is toggled by the user .

When :allow_read is switch OFF , then :allow_update and :allow_create should be switched OFF too...

So I wrote the following js code to handle this case ...

```
 $('input[name="permission[allow_read]"]').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function(event, state) {
      if (event.type == "switchChange" && state == false){
        $('input[name="permission[allow_update]"]').bootstrapSwitch('state', false, true); // disallow update
        $('input[name="permission[allow_create]"]').bootstrapSwitch('state', false, true); // disallow create
      }
    });
```

But it's not working fine ...  as it's inserting and OFF text before the switch, however the toggling is performed :

[image: display after toggle of :allow_read button]

what could be wrong ?

thanks for feedback

--UPDATE ---
forgot to add the generated HTML...

```
<div class="col-sm-9">
  <input name="permission[allow_read]" type="hidden" value="0">
  <div class="bootstrap-switch bootstrap-switch-wrapper bootstrap-switch-on bootstrap-switch-medium bootstrap-switch-animate bootstrap-switch-id-permission_allow_read">
      <div class="bootstrap-switch-container">
          <span class="bootstrap-switch-handle-on bootstrap-switch-success">OUI</span>
          <label class="bootstrap-switch-label">&nbsp;</label>
          <span class="bootstrap-switch-handle-off bootstrap-switch-default">NON</span>
          <input type="checkbox" value="1" checked="checked" name="permission[allow_read]" id="permission_allow_read">
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is something wrong with html generated by the Rails view helper and Bootstrap switch...
back to a standard html tag , it works correctly

```
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <p  class='col-sm-3 control-label' >READ</p>
                  <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <input id="allow_read" name="permission[allow_read]" type="checkbox" value="1"  data-size ='medium', data-on-color ='success' data-on-text = "YES" data-off-text = "NO" />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

and similar switches for update and create....  the js script runs very well...